# UiWebView with several tabs

Tags: swift, tabs, uiwebview

I have done a lot of searches but I haven't found anything to help me to create (with the UiWebView) several pages/tabs, like every browsers (Chrome/Safari for example ...).

I'm searching how to create and manage several tabs in Swift.

Comment: You may have to design your own custom view to have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TabBarController to achieve this goal. See the simple illustration below. However, to implement a more robust app you should understand how to programmatically implement a tabBarController which allows you to create as many tabs as required by the pages you plan to display. In the illustration below, I used a storyboard in which a UIViewController segues to a 2-tab view. Each tab view is driven by the same WebViewController. In viewDidAppear function of the WebViewController, I use the tabBarController.selectedIndex to determine which tab was selected and pick a corresponding url from an array to be displayed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // segue to tabViewController after initial viewController becomes visible
    // wont work in viewDidLoad.
    // In robust implementation you should use a view controller array to define
    // variable number of tab controllers depending on the number of pages

    performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToTab", sender: self)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}

import UIKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {
var webView: UIWebView!
var myUrls = ["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com"]
var url: NSURL!
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let webView = UIWebView(frame: view.bounds)
    if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
        let index = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        println("selectedIndex = \(index)")
        url = NSURL(string: myUrls[index])
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

    }

    view.addSubview(webView)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```